# Is it possible to have screenshots in any other section rather than the screenshots section?

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

At WordPress.org plugin, is it possible to have screenshots in any other section rather than the screenshots section? For example. Can I create a section called "Manual" and then have some screenshots there?

Comment: What screenshot section?

Comment: Sorry.. i meant from the README.TXT file.

Comment: That is even more confusing.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt there you have the screenshot section. I would like to know if is possible to have other sections with screenshots.

Comment: Ok. Got it. You are talking about hosting a plugin in the WordPress repo. Now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [readme.txt file](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt), the "Screenshots" section is a special section.  The WordPress plugin repository checks your Assets folder (or the folder containing readme.txt) for images named in a certain way and corresponds them to the entries in this section.  I don't believe it is possible to attach images in the same way in any other section.

Markdown does provide a [syntax for including images](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img):

```
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
```

However, I tried to make this work in the [WordPress readme.txt validator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/validator/), and I couldn't.  It looks like the plugin repo strips these out, but I haven't actually tried it in a plugin's readme.txt and committed it to see what would happen.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think it looks in an assets folder. I'm pretty sure it looks in the same folder as the readme.txt file

Comment: @bungeshea, it checks the /assets folder first for the screenshot images.  If they aren't found there, it looks for the images in the folder containing the stable readme.txt.  Take a look at the [official readme.txt documentation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt), and scroll down to the Screenshots section for more details.  I've edited the answer to clarify.